# Recommendations for an online beginners guide to OLAP databases in Microsoft SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, olap

As our products gather more and more data, and more and more demands are made of reporting against that data we really need to stop trying to report against the primary OLTP databases and get that primary data into a corresponding OLAP database and report against that.  However that’s about where my OLAP knowledge stops.

So my question boils down to this:  Can any of you StackOverflow people recommend a good set of (preferably online) learning resources to educate proficient SQL using software developers in the ways of OLAP?  Specifically the mechanics of how one should go about the ETL (with SSIS I presume) of source data in your OLTP databases into their corresponding OLAP one(s)?

As you can see I know just enough about this to know that I know nearly nothing about it.  Whilst this conscious incompetence is a recent improvement from my earlier unconscious incompetence I would like to elevate this to at least conscious competence!

*update*

The answer to [A Developers guide to SQL Server Analysis Services and OLAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798445/a-developers-guide-to-sql-server-analysis-services-and-olap) by [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95589/eric) lists a couple of decent sounding books (duly added to my Amazon wish list), but being a cheapskate (and impatient) I really would like online resources I can access now and for free rather than books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest starting out here http://www.msdev.com/Pivot/Trainings.aspx

Filter by Business Intelligence and watch Ola Ekdahl's videos (there's hours and hours of material) on concepts and introduction and more advanced topics.

You can also access (for free) - virtual labs that guide you through the steps to get comfortable with the concepts and products.

Answer (score 0):

Try Kimball's website for a number of useful articles and papers: http://www.kimballgroup.com/html/articles.html

Comment: Just got and started reading "The Data Warehouse Toolkit" by Ralph Kimball (ISBN 0-471-15337-0) having found a second hand copy on amazon.  So far its "from first principals" approach is just what I needed.