# Extracting Data from multiple archive tables(Sql Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, report

I am developing a report in report builder 3.0 where i am extracting data from a table dbo.odcalls.
now the problem is this table is archived on monthly basis on a seperate database(HN_Backup) and i need to combine the data from all archived tables and tables which will be generated in future and give the results . i have 2 approaches to do it:

1. union all tables but the issue will be for archive tables in future as 'if exist' will not work with union.
2. insert every new row added in odcalls to a diffrent table with only inser/update (not delete) , i would avoid using triggers or replication for this.

please let me know if there is any workaround for the same. thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the `UNION ALL` solution - just build the `SQL statement` dynamically and then execute it using `EXEC sp_executesql`. While you are building the `SQL statement` you can check if something exits.

Comment: but lets say the current table is odcalls , archived tables are odcalls_2014_10,odcalls_2014_11... and the future archive tables would be like odcalls_2015_01,odcalls_2015_02... and i am doing union all, and check if exist , it will not work , besides i have to predefine the future archive tables.

Comment: Are the tables in the context of one database?

Comment: the tables have same structure but archived tables are in different DB . Actually , i was hoping to create something like a dynamic view that will check all tables with name like 'odcalls%' and union them . or something like moving every new entry to a separate table, from where i can run the report. but not sure which is beeter and how to do it a better way

Comment: actually i cant make changes in the current structure. so, for that reason i was wondering what would be the best and easiest way to move every new entry in ODCalls to another aggregated table , from where i will run my report.

Comment: Is the table name always following this format `odcalls_YYYY_MM`?

Comment: yes, thats the format for all archived tables

Comment: Maybe worth to shift to OLAP techniques? You can search Stackoverflow for initial recommendations [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798445/a-developers-guide-to-sql-server-analysis-services-and-olap).

Comment: What is the purpose of archiving? To save space or improve performance? Either way you may be better served to use table partitioning or a partitioned view.

Answer (score 1):

Let's create some tables:

```
CREATE TABLE odcalls_2014_10
(
    [ID] TINYINT
)

CREATE TABLE odcalls_2014_11
(
    [ID] TINYINT
)

CREATE TABLE odcalls_2014_12
(
    [ID] TINYINT
)

CREATE TABLE odcalls_2015_01
(
    [ID] TINYINT
)

....
```

Then you can build a dynamic SQL statement which can be put in stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF
(
    (
    SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ' + [TABLE_NAME]
    FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
    WHERE [TABLE_TYPE] = 'BASE TABLE'
        AND [TABLE_NAME] LIKE 'odcalls_%'
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,11
    ,''
);

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQLStatement;
```

Each time the procedure is executed all `odcalls` table will be included.